# Hacer un formulario en Drupal 7 sin módulos

Tags: drupal, drupal7

espero pueda ser claro, soy nuevo en Drupal y he podido aprender lo que tiene para poder extender su funcionalidad en un sitio web. Pude crear una plantilla y poderla asociar a un nodo gracias a un módulo y a muchas carcterísticas que he podido hacer con la ayuda de los módulos. Mi pregunta es que mi desarrollo lo he estado haciendo más con el tema y sin tantos módulos, he visto tutoriales que por ejemplo para crear un simple formulario se requiere de un módulo. Se puede hacer un formulario usando el tema sin la necesidad de crearlo como módulo?

He intentado usando `mytheme_menu()` y `mytheme_theme()` pero nunca se renderiza en una plantilla personalizada.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con hacer un formulario usando el tema?

Comment: Si, es que tengo una plantilla personalizada (page--custom--mipagina.tpl) y en esa quiero que un formulario aparezca si lo renderizo desde template.php de mi tema.

Ejemplo:

`function mytheme_filter_form() {
 
 $form['filter_field1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select'
);

} `

Si estoy en un tema el renderizar este formulario no lo hace en la página personalizada aunque se lo diga con la función `mytheme_theme()`

Que puedo hacer?

Comment: No controlo mucho la API de formularios, yo solía usar el modulo webform. Igual esto te puede ayudar: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/104025